# "WP Job Manager" custom query (how to filter)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a query with custom args in order to show only certain posts.

These are my args:

```
    $args = array(

        'post_type' => 'job_listing',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_type',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => 'Startups'
            )
        )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

..and here's my loop:

```
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <div class="entry-content" id="entry-content-anchor">   
                    <?php
                        the_content();
                        echo do_shortcode('[jobs show_map="false"]');
                    ?>  
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-## -->             
        <?                      
    endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>
```

..but how do I get wp job manager to use these args?

I'm guessing adding a filter in my functions.php ..but which function to filter and how?

Answer (score -1):

Referencing your wp_query in the while loop seems like it would help...

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

You also may want to utilize the `get_job_listings()` function:

```
$query = get_job_listings( array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'job_types'         => 'startups'
) );
```

Then do while loop as per above.

But the easiest way is probably to remove the loop from your code altogether and just use the shortcode to do everything:

```
echo do_shortcode("[jobs job_types='startups' show_filters=false]");
```

https://wpjobmanager.com/document/shortcode-reference/

Comment: Hi @git-e-up :-)

It's most likely utilizing the get_job_listings() function to get WP Job Manager to use the custom args ... but can you give me an example on how to do that? 

I just can't seem to figure it out and get it working :-/

Comment: I edited the post with the get_job_listings function. I presume the slug for Startups is startups.

Comment: That half way worked @git-e-up.

The while loop gets the arguments ..but running the "echo do_shortcode('[jobs show_map="false"]')" I still can't get WP Job Manager to use the new args :-/

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine running the shortcode in the loop is a problem. I didn't notice that before. Sorry... Updating answer now. Please give it thumbs up or whatever if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me :-/ The problem is that I have args that the WP Job Manager shortcodes can't handle (example my custom taxonomy "job_listing_type"). I therefore need WP Job Manager to use my custom query with these args ...buuuut a BIG thanks for even trying to help! :-)

Comment: Okay. No problem. Are you already using the job categories taxonomy that comes with wp job manager?